# Round number to 6 decimal places perl Excel::Writer:XLSX

Tags: perl

How do I output a number rounded to 6 decimal places to an `Excel` sheet using the `Excel::Writer::XLSX` package in `Perl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would round the number in Perl using `sprintf` function

```
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

# Create a new Excel workbook
my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'perl.xlsx' );

$worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();
$worksheet->write( 'A1', sprintf("%.6f", 1/3) );
```

The cell A1 will contain 0.333333 value

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of the Excel file formats employ styles (referred to as 'formats'), which can be shared among the cells. The `Excel::Writer::XLSX` provides the interface to [create the new formats](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm#add_format%28_%25properties_%29), and to [assign them to the cells](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm#write%28_$row,_$column,_$token,_$format_%29). Search for `numeric formats` in [the official examples](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX/Examples.pm#Example:_formats.pl) on how to use them.

P.S. I haven't used formats with the XLSX files personally - only with the older `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel` for the XLS files. But the interface is literally the same. And the author of the modules is the same.